# Lifetime of a light bulb

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Light bulbs average 800 hours of life (here the life time of a bulb follows an $\exp(1/800)$ distribution). Buy 1000 bulbs. Find the probability that the fourth bulb has gone out before 3 hours have passed.

Comment: just to be clear, what do you mean by the fourth bulb? ... just a random bulb indexed 4?

Comment: To clarify the last sentence: does it mean "find the probability for at least four bulbs to have gone out before 3 hours have passed?"

Comment: I'm told that this is a problem that makes use of extreme value theory. Here, there is a "left edge" at $x= 0$; for $n$ large, the limiting distribution of the quantity $n(x_n)$ should be some type of exponential. Any light that could be shed on this problem would be greatly appreciated (no pun intended)

This problem only asks that we find the probability that the fourth bulb has burned out before 3 hours have passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that a specific bulb dies in time $\le 3$ is $1-e^{-3/800}$. Call this $p$.

Then the probability that the fourth shortest-lived bulb has life $\le 3$ is $1$ minus the probability that $3$ or fewer bulbs are dead by that time.

This can be calculated by the standard formula for the *binomial* distribution.

We can alternately use the **Poisson** approximation to the binomial, or by direct use of the Poisson. The mean number of "deaths" in $3$ hours is $1000\cdot\frac{3}{800}$. Let $\mu$ be this number. Then the probability of $k$ deaths in $3$ hours is approximately $e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^k}{k!}$. Calculate the sum of the probabilities, $0$ to $3$, and subtract the sum from $1$.

**Remark:** Lifetimes of the bulbs, at least if they are installed in the same building, are not independent. Think power surge!

Also, the exponential is not a really good model for bulb lifetime. There is a peak of early deaths, because of manufacturing defects. And the exponential distribution is appropriate for things that die but do not age, like radioisotopes. Lightbulbs age.

Comment: This is a great explanation. The computation is: .72. Does this seem a little high? If the lifetime is 800 hours, these can't be very good light bulbs. Any intuition you have would be great.

Comment: $\mu = 3.75$, no? I did make a computation error in my first answer but for $k = 0\dots 3$ we get .51

Comment: Yes, I miscalculated (expression in post is right). Note there is some ambiguity in the problem, they **might** mean that exactly $4$ are dead at time $3$. Then prob. is $e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu4}{4!}$.

Comment: I also get about $0.516$.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand why such a large probability makes sense. 

Because some light bulbs will last forever (think of the distribution for $\text{exp}(\lambda)$, the mean is going to be huge. 

Thank you again, Andre!